# How can I get the d3 axis ticks to match my data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale, attr, rect

Here's my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>

     var dataArray=[{"letter":"a", "value":20},
                {"letter":"b", "value":40}, 
                {"letter":"c", "value":50},
                {"letter":"m", "value":60}];
 console.log(dataArray)

 var width=500;
 var height=500;

 var widthScale=d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 60])
            .range([0, width]);

 var heightScale=d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(dataArray.map(function(d){ return d.letter }))
            .range([0,height-125]);

 var letterScale=d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,26])
        .range(["A","B","c","d"])

 var color=d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,60])
            .range(["red", "blue"]);

 var x_axis=d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(12)
        .scale(widthScale);

 var y_axis=d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(4)
        .tickFormat(function (d) {return d})
        .scale(heightScale);

 var canvas=d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(25, 0)");

 var bars=canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataArray)
        .enter()
            .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function(d) {return widthScale(d.value);})   
                .attr("height", 50)
                .attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d.value)})
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {return i*100});
// bars.append("text")
//      .attr("x", function(d) {return widthScale(d)/2})
//      .attr("y", function(d) {return -heightScale(d)})
//      .style("stroke-width", 6)
//      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
//      .style("font-size", "34px")
//      .style("fill", "black")
//      .text(function(d) {return console.log(d);});

 canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(5, 375)")
    .call(x_axis);

 canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(5,0)")
    .call(y_axis)

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out how to get the y axis ticks to match the data and line up with the bars? OR as you can see in the commented out code, I struggled to get the text to appear. The correct text (the numbers) would show up in the elements in dev tools, but not on the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a D3 problem, but a problem regarding statistics and dataviz: you said "I can't figure out how to get the y axis ticks to match the data", but what data? There is none!

Your dataset is just an array of 4 values. If you want to draw one horizontal bar for each value, the x-axis will show a quantitative variable (the values: 20, 40, 50, 60). But your y-axis only shows the different bars: its **categorical**, not **quantitative**. You can have, for instance, *oranges, apples, bananas and limes* for these 4 bars.

So, your y-axis has to be `heightScale = d3.scale.ordinal()`, instead of `linear`, and you have to set the categorical values of the bars, as I did here with an array of objects:

```
var dataArray = [
    {
        "fruit": "orange",
        "value": 20
    },
    {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "value": 40
    },
    {
        "fruit": "banana",
        "value": 50
    },
    {
        "fruit": "lime",
        "value": 60
    }
]
```

After that, you set the domain like this:

```
heightScale.domain(dataArray.map(function(d){ return d.fruit }));
```

Then, you don't need to set the y position using `i * 100`. Instead, you can set it in a more flexible way:

```
.attr("y", function(d){ return heightScale(d) });
```

Just change the "fruits" for your letters (a, b, c, d) and you'll have what you want.

Comment: I have made the changes above, except

Comment: Except the y axis now returns extremely long on the page